# Unable to locate table element generated via ajax using Webdriver

Tags: ajax, selenium, xpath, webdriver, testng

I am new to Webdriver, I can not let you know the site name and credentials as this is an ongoing project of my company.
I am getting stuck a place, in a page of that website, there is a table generated via ajax on runtime and all data inside it also generated on runtime, there is an element inside that table with xpath as `html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a`, but when I tried to find this element using webdriver, webdriver is unable to locate the element and I am getting an error message as

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a"}
Command duration or timeout: 50.10 seconds
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=14.0.1, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

My code for this is

```
 Assert.assertEquals(FrameWorkBase.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a")).getText(),24514);
```

When I entered the above xpath in firebug, it is locating the element, means xpath is correct.

Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: I think this is because the table is there in nested div which i can't access directly through webdriver, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things :
1. Try having an explicit wait on your element, something to the effect..call this method for your elements.. read [more](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

```
public WebElement waitForElementToBeVisible(WebDriver driver, By by){

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
    return element;
}
```

2. Your xpath `html/body/main/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a`  looks a bit brittle since it's absolute.  Try finding a unique identifier (an id would be best) for one of the elements and then find your way to your element.

Answer (score -1):

If the table is ajax-generated, perhaps you should implement some sort of `waitForElement` instead of a simple `findElement`? In my tests I have written a method that waits until jQuery is ready, and it works quite nice. I suspect the reason for your exception is that the element simply isn't present when you are trying to find it.

You could also try first to get only a higher-level element and then work your way deeper. That way you can get a clue what element is missing and see what kind of wait is needed.

Comment: i put 50 seconds implicit wait before this statement which is i think enough for the element to load.

Comment: Yes, it should be, but it still isn't getting you where you are going. I'm suggesting something you could try and maybe would lead you further.